# Rename a file inside a zip with ruby

Tags: ruby, zip

I am trying to rename a single file from an zip archive using zip gem in Ruby.

```
zip_path = "C:/Downloads/"
zipfile_name = "C:/Downloads/02004 - 1850 W PINHOOK RD Lafayette LA.zip"
old_name = 'Reports.xls'
new_filename = 'Reports.csv'

Zip::ZipFile.open('C:/Downloads/02004 - 1850 W PINHOOK RD Lafayette LA.zip').each do |zipfile|
  files = zipfile.select(&:file?)
  file = files.find{|f| f.name == old_name}
  zipfile.rename(file.name, new_filename) if file
end
  end`

This is the code that I use and I get the the following error:
**NoMethodError: private method `select' called for #<Zip::Entry:0x00000000062ff098>
./features/step_definitions/rename_csv_definition.rb:21:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
./features/step_definitions/rename_csv_definition.rb:20:in `/^I rename the excel file to csv$/'**

Any suggestions?
```

Answer (score 0):

Working example:

```
$ touch 1.csv 2.csv 3.csv
$ zip -r files.zip 1.csv 2.csv 3.csv
$ touch zip_rename.rb
```

```rb
# zip_rename.rb

require 'zip/zip'

zip_path = './'
zipfile_name = 'files.zip'

old_name = '1.csv'
new_filename = '777.csv'

Zip::ZipFile.open(zip_path + zipfile_name) do |zipfile|
  if zipfile.find_entry(old_name)
    zipfile.rename(old_name, new_filename)
  end
end
```

Check archive content:

```
$ unzip -l files.zip
Archive:  files.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  03-18-2021 18:37   3.csv
        0  03-18-2021 18:37   2.csv
        0  03-18-2021 19:43   777.csv
---------                     -------
        0                     3 files
```

Note, that `rename` method is avaliable for `Zip::ZipFile` object(`zipfile`) and take `Zip::ZipEntry` instance file name as argument
Here is the source
[rubyzip Zip::File#rename](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rubyzip/rubyzip/Zip%2FFile:rename)